# Angular 2: How to override a ng-bootstrap template

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I need to add some custom button to the right of an Accordion, to do that I need to override the ng-bootstrap Accordion template. How do we do that in Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

you have to firstly copy the whole code for that component then make some editing as per your requirement and than use that component 
(relative path) instead of directly using that component from `node_modules` etc.

for example normaly we use components like

```
import { abc } from 'ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

than import this component like this

```
import { abc } from 'Relative_path_from_folder';
```

Comment: But that would not allow easy update to new version of ng-bootstrap, I may end up redoing stuff for each release

Comment: Yeah exactly, either you have to wait until ng-bootstrap add that feature or either you have to update manually , which one suits you best choice is Yours !!!